# Remove vertical space between <span> and <list> entries

Tags: css, r-markdown

I searched stackoverflow and did not any similar question posted. I apologize if I missed one.

I am creating a R presentation in RStudio. I want to remove the vertical space between "Preprocessing" and List item. I am not able to find a solution. I also want to remove the vertical space between the list items. See the code below and the screenshot :

```
<style>
.reveal p {font-size: 35px;}
.reveal ul,
.reveal li,
.reveal ol {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;  
}
.reveal li:after,
.reveal li:before {
     height: 0px;  // or px or em or whatever
     width: 0px;  // or whatever space you want
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.mypara2 {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
}
</style>


First Slide
========================================================

<span class="mypara2">Preprocessing</span> 
<ol>
  <li>List1</li>
  <li>List2</li>
  <li>List3</li>
</ol>
```

[image]

**Update:**

This is the screenshot after I made changes as per @phil.

[image]

Comment: you can reset your line-height, reduce paddings and margins down to zero, use a p here not a span, span are to be used among text or other inline-tag, it is meant for phrasing content ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is a margin of your `<OL> element`.
Most browsers will display the `<ol> element` with the following default values:

```
ol {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp)

Solutions are pretty simple:

1. Add `.reveal ol { margin-top: 0; }` in your stylesheet
2. Add `<ol style="margin-top: 0;">` inline
3. Use a reset ["Google Search"](https://www.google.com/?q=html5%20css%20reset)
4. (not yet wide supported: use `.reveal ol { all: unset }` )

[Can i use all?](http://caniuse.com/#search=all)

```css
.reveal li,
.reveal ol {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.reveal ol {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
span.mypara2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>First Slide</h3>
<hr>
<div class="reveal">
  <span class="mypara2">Preprocessing</span> 
  <ol>
    <li>List1</li>
    <li>List2</li>
    <li>List3</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I accepted your solution and love the <Run code snippet> option. It works great in regular html file. However, I am using RMarkdown, and it is not working there. I think this might be some bug with RPresentation in RStudio. I am posting the screen shot in my main post. Any ideas why this happenning?

Comment: Hmmm, later on the day i will help you look for the problem

Comment: @peterV got it..  make span display block not inl8ne-block

Comment: that worked!  It's been a long time since I have played with css. Thanks for all your help! +1 for you.

Comment: Feel free to contact me any time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the top margin of the `<ol>` element to zero:

```
<ol style="margin-top: 0;">
  <li>List1</li>
  <li>List2</li>
  <li>List3</li>
</ol>
```

Of course, can also do this using your stylesheet, which is in most cases more preferable.

Comment: Please don't advise someone to use inline styling. It's bad practise

Comment: True (to some extent). I added a note in my answer.

Comment: @JeroenNoten: Was just about to answer the same thing! Nice job.

Comment: @GustvandeWal ooh and what about mails and css ? no inline ?

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs I haven't really built a lot of emails, but I think you can loosen the rules when you're composing these ;)

Comment: Therefore my 'to some extent' ;-)